Запускается только последняя строка shell script
У меня есть shell script
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS bot sudo python bot/main.py
screen -dmS Bublik_zozhbot sudo python Bublik_zozhbot/main.py
screen -dmS test_bot python test_bot/main.py

Но при запуске создаётся только последний screen

Логичный вопрос — а кто вводит пароль в sudo?

Даже если убрать sudo запускается только последний скрипт

А как вы определили, что другие скрипты не запускаются? Может, на самом деле запускаются и мгновенно завершают работу?

При вводе команды вручную скрипт запускается

Ну это ещё ничего не значит, может, в момент запуска shell-скрипта происходит что-то, что не происходит при запуске вручную? Как минимум попробуйте хотя бы sleep добавить, чтобы screen не завершался сразу после завершения работы скрипта, чтобы у вас было время прочитать текст ошибки (если таковая имеется) screen -dmS bot bash -c 'python bot/main.py; sleep 300'

Если ввести команды вручную, то всё работает, но при запуске из shell скрипта запускается только последняя строка

Вы повторили то, что вы уже писали. Вы sleep попробовали?
